# Android accesing database error database disk image is malformed when opening from pc

Tags: android

I hope than someone could help me with this problem.I have a SQLITE 3 database file stored in sdcard. When use the database from my android app there is no problem the app is working fine. The question is that i would like to open that file from my pc using other program but the following error is shown "database disk image is malformed"

```
public class DBHelper{

private SQLiteDatabase database; 

public static DBHelper getInstance()
{
    if(instancia == null)
        instancia = new DBHelper();
    return instancia;
}


public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase()
{
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(nombre_fichero, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    return database;
}

private SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase()
{
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(nombre_fichero, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    return database;
}

private void close()
{
    database.close();
}

Select and insert parameters...
```

I am not extending from sqlitehelper because I need the file from sdcard
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to get the database onto your pc? Are you using Eclipse?

If so, in Eclipse, run your app and then click the DDMS button top right of the Eclipse screen. Navigate to the sdcard within the mnt directory and find your database. Click on it and then click on the 'pull a file from the device' button at the top right. This will save the db to your pc where you can open it in other programs. I use sqliteman.

If the db is in your devices internal memory, you can't access it in this manner. The only way I've found to get the db onto the pc is to create an activity which backs up the db and then emails it to me.

Comment: thanks for the reply. My db file is on the sdcard for debugging I use a nexus phone. I open the db file on rthe sdcard that could be a problem??

Comment: are you putting the sdcard into a pc card reader, or something like that? That won't work - you need to follow the steps above.